# Screen zooms out when tapping on a TextField

Tags: ios, typescript, next.js

I am working on a NextJS project, and when I'm testing on my iOS device, I notice that my screen suddenly zooms out when I tap on any TextField. Currently, I am using Next v12.2.6.

My `_app.tsx` file looks like this:

```
import "../styles/globals.css";
import type { AppProps } from "next/app";
import Head from "next/head";

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) {
  return (
    <>
      <Head>
        <meta httpEquiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
      </Head>
      <div suppressHydrationWarning id="root">
        {typeof window !== "undefined" ? <Component {...pageProps} /> : null}
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

export default MyApp;
```

I've also read on [this GitHub thread](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/7176) that you can disable scaling manually, however, that seems to not be recommended. On the same thread, they suggest to move the `<meta name="viewport" ... />` tag to the `_app` file, however, I've already done that and the error persists. Is there another solution I can try?